# Styling polar axes in PolarPlot

Tags: plotting, style

You can style the axes in `Plot` with `AxesStyle`.  For example, the following code makes the axes red.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Red]
```

I cannot seem to find a way to style the polar axes in `PolarPlot`.  `AxesStyle` does not work and there is no `PolarAxesStyle` function.  I was hoping to get this code below to work but it doesn't.

```
PolarPlot[θ, {θ, 0, 3 π}, PolarAxes -> True, AxesStyle -> Red]
```

Is this a missing feature in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I do not know why it does not work. But Will this work for your? `PolarPlot[θ, {θ, 0, 3 π}, BaseStyle -> Red, PolarAxes -> True]`

Comment: Yes it does.  Interesting...  It would seem their naming scheme is not uniform.  There must be a good reason for this... that I am not aware of.  But it seems a little counterintuitive to me.  Thank you!

Comment: According to help, I think it should have worked. It might be a bug. I do not know. May be someone else would know better what is going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`AxesStyle` modifies the *Cartesian* axes, *not* the polar ones:

```
PolarPlot[θ, {θ, 0, 4 Pi},
  AxesStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[16, Orange]}
]
```

[image: polar plot with colored Cartesian axes]

I could not find a built-in way to modify the polar axes, so after taking a look at the structure of the `Graphics` object generated by `PolarPlot`, I came up with the following **helper function that modifies the graphics primitives** corresponding to axes, ticks, and labels on the polar axes.

By default:

- If these features are not present, nothing happens to the plot even if options were selected;
- If no options are specified, then the defaults output by `PolarPlot` will be left alone.

This is `colorPolarAxes`:

```
Clear[colorPolarAxes]

Options[colorPolarAxes] = 
  {PolarAxesStyle -> {}, PolarLabelsStyle -> {}, PolarTicksStyle -> {}};

colorPolarAxes[plot_Graphics, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 ReplaceAll[plot,
  {
   Text[Style[lbl__, {}], pos__] :> Text[Style[lbl, OptionValue[PolarLabelsStyle]], pos],
   Style[Line[def__], {}] :> Style[Line[def], OptionValue[PolarTicksStyle]],
   Circle[options__] :> Style[Circle[options], OptionValue[PolarAxesStyle]]
  }
 ]
```

Here is an example of its use:

```
colorPolarAxes[
  PolarPlot[θ, {θ, 0, 4 Pi}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", None}],
  PolarAxesStyle -> Orange,
  PolarLabelsStyle -> {Darker@Green, 14, Italic},
  PolarTicksStyle -> {Blue, Thick}
]
```

[image: plot with colored polar axes, ticks and labels]

Comment: Excellent, I remember scratching my head over this back when it was posted.

Answer (score 4):

```
PolarPlot[\[Theta], {\[Theta], 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.006], Black], 
 PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Black], PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick, 14]]
```

[image: Try this once]